# All elements in Android studio are automatically align to upper left. How can I fix it?

Tags: android

As you can see the picture, all elements like text view or buttons or whatever in Android studio are automatically align to upper left. It will automatically align to upper-left whenever I change the position by dragging it to other position. How can I fix this issue?

Moreover, I just import project from github and all the important file indicated as red, but it does not have any problem for building/ running project. How can I fix this issue too?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Children of a RelativeLayout are positioned using attributes like `android:layout_alignParentTop` and `android:layout_below`. Read more about them here:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative

Also, just so you know, the Android world has pretty much moved on from RelativeLayout. ConstraintLayout does the same thing and more, and is better in just about every way.

Comment: I know that I could position them by using android:layout_alignParentTop and android:layout_below, but the main problem is that They are automatically position to upper left conner even I draged them into somewhere. what i wanted to do is for positioning them into certain position i just solved this by enabling Auto-connection to parent